# how to set maxlen when subclassing a deque

Tags: python, subclass, deque

I am trying to subclass a deque, but can't work out how to set the maxlen.

is there a `__maxlen__` ?

EDIT: - is the following 'Bad' python?

```
from collections import deque

class MinMax(deque):
    def __init__(self):
        deque.__init__(self, maxlen=2)

mm = MinMax()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the super-class constructor:

```
class dequePlus(collections.deque):
    def __init__(self, iterable):
        collections.deque.__init__(self, iterable, 100)
```

Answer (score 5):

You should rather call the `super()` constructor properly

```
class dequePlus(collections.deque):
    def __init__(self, iterable):
        super(dequePlus, self).__init__(iterable, 100)
```